# Reticulate not importing pandas in R

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I have installed reticulate. And I have gone to my R profile and set `Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "C:\\Users\\User1\\anaconda3")`

Then in an R Markdown file I've run the following code:

````
```{r}
library(reticulate)
```

```{python}
use_python("C:\\Users\\User1\\anaconda3")
```

```{python}
import pandas as pd
```
````

But when I run the first python chunk I get this error:

```
Error in python_config(python_version, required_module, forced = "RETICULATE_PYTHON") : Error 1 occurred running C:/Users/User1/anaconda3/python.exe
```

And the second chunk gives me this error:

```
Error in python_config(python_version, required_module, forced = "RETICULATE_PYTHON") : Error 1 occurred running C:/Users/User1/anaconda3/python.exe
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that those `{python}` chunks are independent of the `reticulate` calls and configs that you use in `{r}` chunks (since they are interpreted by the markdown engine), and if you need to set the reticulate path, you'll have to do it in a global config chunk at the beginning.